# LNK 2005 & LNK 1169 errors in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-c++, runtime-error

I am getting LNK 2005 and LKN 1169 errors (only one of the latter while having seven of the former) in my code. As far as I am concerned, everything looks fundamentally correct. I would be truly grateful to anyone who can point me in the right direction toward a solution. The code I am working on is a linked list implementation of a stack. The code and the list of errors are shone below.

**LinkedList.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H

using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

class LinkedList
{
public:
    LinkedList(); // Constuctor
    ~LinkedList(); // Destructor
    void push(int number); // Pushes an element with the value number into the stack
    int pop(); // Pops an element from the stack
    int isEmpty(); // Returns 1 if the stack is empty, 0 otherwise
    int numOfElements(); // Returns the number of elements in the stack
    void printElements(); // Print out the current stack to the console

private:
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    int maxSize;
};

#endif
```

**LinkedList.cpp**

```
#include "LinkedList.h"

LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
    maxSize = 20;
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
    Node* temp = head;

    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
        delete head;
        head = temp;
    }
}

void LinkedList::push(int number)
{
    if (numOfElements() == maxSize)
    {
        cout << endl << endl << "The stack is full. Cannot push.";
    }

    else if (head == NULL)
    {
        Node* n = new Node;
        n->data = number;
        n->next = NULL;

        head = n;
        tail = n;

        cout << endl << endl << number << " was successfully pushed into the stack!";
    }

    else
    {
        Node* n = new Node;
        n->data = number;
        n->next = head;
        head = n;

        cout << endl << endl << number << " was successfully pushed into the stack!";
    }
}

int LinkedList::pop()
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        cout << endl << endl << "The stack is empty. Cannot pop.";

        return NULL;
    }

    // Case with only one element
    else if (head == tail)
    {
        Node* temp;
        temp = head;
        delete head;
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;

        return temp->data;
    }

    else
    {
        Node* temp;
        temp = head;
        head = head->next;

        return temp->data;
    }
}

int LinkedList::isEmpty()
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int LinkedList::numOfElements()
{
    if (head == NULL && tail == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    Node* temp = head;
    int counter = 0;

    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        counter++;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    return counter;
}

void LinkedList::printElements()
{
    if (isEmpty() == 0)
    {
        Node* temp = head;

        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            cout << temp->data << endl;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "LinkedList.cpp"

using namespace std;

// Prototypes
void showMenu();

int main()
{
    LinkedList stack; // Demonstrates usage of constructor
    int choice;

    cout << "Welcome to the Linked List Implementation of a Stack!" << endl << endl;    
    showMenu();

    cout << "Please Enter Your Choice: ";
    cin >> choice;

    while (choice < 1 || choice > 6)
    {
        cout << endl << endl << "I am sorry, that is not a valid choice. Please try again." << endl;
        showMenu();

        cout << "Please Enter Your Choice: ";
        cin >> choice;
    }

    if (choice == 1)
    {
        int value;

        cout << endl << endl << "Please enter a positive number that you wish to push into the stack: ";
        cin >> value;

        stack.push(value);
    }

    if (choice == 2)
    {
        int poppedData;

        poppedData = stack.pop();

        cout << endl << endl << poppedData << " was successfully popped from the stack!";
    }

    if (choice == 3)
    {
        int value;

        value = stack.isEmpty();

        if (value == 1)
        {
            cout << endl << endl << "The stack is empty!";
        }

        if (value == 0)
        {
            cout << endl << endl << "The stack is not empty!";
        }
    }

    if (choice == 4)
    {
        int elementsInStack;

        elementsInStack = stack.numOfElements();

        cout << endl << endl << "The number of elements in the stack is " << elementsInStack << ".";
    }

    if (choice == 5)
    {
        cout << endl << endl << "The elements in the stack are as follows:" << endl;

        stack.printElements();
    }

    if (choice == 6)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

void showMenu()
{
    cout << "1. Push" << endl;
    cout << "2. Pop" << endl;
    cout << "3. isEmpty" << endl;
    cout << "4. numOfElements" << endl;
    cout << "5. printElements" << endl;
    cout << "6. Quit" << endl << endl;
}
```

[List of Errors from the Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClRO3.jpg)

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2005 "public: __thiscall LinkedList::LinkedList(void)" (??0LinkedList@@QAE@XZ) already defined in LinkedList.obj Project1    c:\Users\Chase\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Project1\Project1\main.obj 1

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2005 "public: __thiscall LinkedList::~LinkedList(void)" (??1LinkedList@@QAE@XZ) already defined in LinkedList.obj    Project1    c:\Users\Chase\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Project1\Project1\main.obj 1

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2005 "public: int __thiscall LinkedList::isEmpty(void)" (?isEmpty@LinkedList@@QAEHXZ) already defined in LinkedList.obj  Project1    c:\Users\Chase\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Project1\Project1\main.obj 1

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2005 "public: int __thiscall LinkedList::numOfElements(void)" (?numOfElements@LinkedList@@QAEHXZ) already defined in LinkedList.obj  Project1    c:\Users\Chase\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Project1\Project1\main.obj 1

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2005 "public: int __thiscall LinkedList::pop(void)" (?pop@LinkedList@@QAEHXZ) already defined in LinkedList.obj  Project1    c:\Users\Chase\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Project1\Project1\main.obj 1

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2005 "public: void __thiscall LinkedList::printElements(void)" (?printElements@LinkedList@@QAEXXZ) already defined in LinkedList.obj Project1    c:\Users\Chase\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Project1\Project1\main.obj 1

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2005 "public: void __thiscall LinkedList::push(int)" (?push@LinkedList@@QAEXH@Z) already defined in LinkedList.obj   Project1    c:\Users\Chase\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Project1\Project1\main.obj 1

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found  Project1    c:\users\chase\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Project1\Debug\Project1.exe    1

Comment: I suppose at this point you expect someone to break out their trusty crystal ball and use it to read the text of those error messages off your screen. I can't think of any other reasonable explanation for your choice not to include those messages in your post.

Comment: Please copy and paste the text of the errors from the output tab of visual studio and add this to your question.

Comment: It has been added at the very bottom. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: The text would have been better.

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't include the source file for your linked list in main.cpp? The errors seem to indicate that.

Comment: I believe I added the actual text for the errors if that was what you were looking for. And I am certain that that is not the issue. It actually was originally #include "LinkedList.cpp" but I changed it to "LinkedList.h" during my attempts at debugging and forgot to change it back. I edited accordingly.

Comment: Do not put `#include <iostream>` or `using namespace` into the header file and do not include cpp - your previous version was better

Comment: Replace #include "LinkedList.cpp" in your main.cpp with #include "LinkedList.h"

Comment: After you fix the include do a clean build.

Comment: After getting rid of using namespace std and iostream from the header file and placing them in the main and implementation files, along with changing #include "LinkedList.cpp" to #include "LinkedList.h", the program seems to be working. I'll try it some more to see if everything is running smoothly but thank you all for your help!